# Drawing a turtle by using given pair list

Tags: python

all
l m fresh user of python and l have still been in learning process.l would like to ask a question.there is an example question and l did but l would like to learn other methods to do it.l tried many things but they didn't work out.
here is question " a man makes a turn, and then takes some steps forward, and repeats this.Here is list=[(160,10), (-49, 6), (270, 12), (-45,22)].Use a turtle to draw the path taken by the man."
firstly , let me show my code and l run it and work well.

```
import turtle

wn=turtle.Screen()

wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")

wn.title("theman")

man=turtle.Turtle()

klm=[(160,10), (-49, 6), (270, 12), (-45,22)]

def walking_drunk_man():

    for i in range(4):
        (x,y)=klm[i]

        man.color("yellow","red")
        man.forward(y)
        man.left(x)
```

in that code ,Assume: by using given list , how can l draw a turtle if l don't know length of list.(l used range(4) as l knew the length of list).

thanks for any clearification in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate directly through the `klm` without needing to unpack it seperately, or to use `len(klm)` to first obtain the length of the list.

Hope this helps:

```
for x, y in klm:
    man.color("yellow","red")
    man.forward(y)
    man.left(x)
```

Answer (score -2):

how about this?

```
import turtle

wn=turtle.Screen()

wn.bgcolor("lightgreen")

wn.title("theman")

man=turtle.Turtle()

klm=[(160,10), (-49, 6), (270, 12), (-45,22)]

def walking_drunk_man():

    for x, y in klm:

        man.color("yellow","red")
        man.forward(y)
        man.left(x)
```

this uses a language feature called tuple unpacking.

Comment: "this uses a language feature called tuple unpacking". Yes it does - the same feature used by the OP in the same line: `(x,y)=klm[i]`

Comment: thanks for all answers .l tried it and it worked out well.